# Como verificiar se a matriz é simétrica?

Tags: c, array, matriz, lógica

Eu estou fazendo uma atividade da faculdade no qual pede para verificar se a matriz digitada pelo usuário é simétrica ou não.

Eis o meu código:

```
#define TAMANHO 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

    void receberMatriz(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO]);
    void acimaDiagonalPrincipal(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO], int acimaD[6]);
    void abaixoDiagonalPrincipal(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO], int abaixoD[6]);
    void resultadoDiagonaisPrincipais(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO], int acimaD[6], int abaixoD[6]);

        int main(void)
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
            int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO];
            int acimaD[6];
            int abaixoD[6];

                receberMatriz(matriz);
                acimaDiagonalPrincipal(matriz, acimaD);
                abaixoDiagonalPrincipal(matriz, abaixoD);
                resultadoDiagonaisPrincipais(matriz, acimaD, abaixoD);

            return 0;
        }

    void receberMatriz(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO])
    {
        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < TAMANHO; j++)
            {
                printf("Insira valor da posição [%i][%i]: ", i, j);
                scanf("%i", &matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    void acimaDiagonalPrincipal(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO], int acimaD[6])
    {
        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < TAMANHO; j++)
            {
                if(i < j)
                {
                    acimaD[j] = matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void abaixoDiagonalPrincipal(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO], int abaixoD[6])
    {
        int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < TAMANHO; j++)
            {
                if(j > i)
                {
                    abaixoD[j] = matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void resultadoDiagonaisPrincipais(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO], int abaixoD[TAMANHO], int acimaD[TAMANHO])
    {
        int i, j, y;

        for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < TAMANHO; j++)
            {
                printf("[%i]", &matriz[i][j]);
            }

            printf("\n");

        }

        printf("\n");

        for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                if(acimaD[i] != abaixoD[j])
                {
                    printf("A matriz não é simétrica.");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("A matriz é simétrica.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Usei uma `for` para fazer a verificação dos valores acima da diagonal com os abaixo da diagonal. Mas sempre acaba sendo impresso o `printf [TAMANHO]` vezes. Como posso fazer essa verificação? Já tenho os valores em vetores como podem ver porém na hora de definir se é simétrico ou não eu bugo. Acredito que seja a parte mais simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eis o código:

```
int simetrica(int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO]){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < TAMANHO; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] != matriz[j][i])
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

A função retorna 1 caso a matriz for simétrica e 0 caso não for.

Nota que no `for` mais interno o `j` é inicializado com o valor da variável `i + 1`, isso porque só é necessário verificar se a diagonal superior é igual a inferior. 
Verificar as duas partes seria redundante (se a = b é porque b = a).

Comment: Entendi! Mas no caso, eu tenho dois vetores que contem os valores das casas acima da diagonal e abaixo da diagonal, posso substituir as matrizes no if por elas né?, vou implementar aqui!

Comment: Poderia ainda otimizar um tico a mais fazendo `j = i + 1`, já que não faz sentido comparar um número consigo mesmo

Comment: Não faça isso acho que é melhor mesmo usar a matriz ao invés dos 2 vetores, até porque os valores que estão nos vetores não estão certos. E segundo argumento da função `abaixoDiagonalPrincipal` só funciona para matrizes 3x3. @LelreFerreira

Comment: Muito bem visto! @JeffersonQuesado